# mvc view find matching row in table using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am updating my row using ajax call now I want to update my row with the updated data without refreshing the page,for now I am matching for DisplayName but I want to match it with ID as id is unique and my id is contained in hidden field inside a table.How to match it.

ajax call and javascript

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   function SuspendSharing(selectedContact)
{
    var url="@Url.Action("SuspendedSharing", "Sharing")";
    var data= { Id: selectedContact };
    var type="GET";
    CallGet(url, data, type, function (data) { onSuccess(data, selectedContact); });
}
function onSuccess(data, selectedContact) {
    data = JSON.parse(data);
    $("#message_toast").hide();
    var path="@Url.Content("~/Content/MessasgeTemplate.html")";
    $("#message_toast").load(path);
    $("#SuccessMessage").text();
    $("#message_toast").fadeIn("slow", function () { $(this).fadeOut(3000, function () { $(this).children().remove(); }); });
    var contactSelector = "td:contains('"+selectedContact+"')";
    $contactRow = $(contactSelector).closest("tr");
    $contactRow.find("td:nth-child(5)").text("test");
}
function CallGet(url, data, type, onSuccess)
{
    $.ajax({

        type: type,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (resultdata) {
            onSuccess(resultdata);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

view

```
 <table class="table table-striped m-b-none" id="sharingTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="bg bg-blue">
                        Name
                    </th>

                    <th class="bg bg-blue">
                        Shared Details
                    </th>

                    <th class="bg bg-blue">
                        Last Used
                    </th>
                    <th class="bg bg-blue">
                        Status
                    </th>
                    <th class="bg bg-blue">
                        Action
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in sharing)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" value="@item.ID"/>
                            @item.Prefix @item.DisplayName

                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @{
                                foreach (var report in item.SharedReports)
                                {
                                    <img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("Content/images/sharingReport/{0}.png", report))">

                                }
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @item.LastUsed
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @{ var staus = (ContactStatusTypes) item.Status; }
                            @staus
                        </td>
                        <td width="160">
                            <a class="inline m-sm pointer editSharing" href="@Url.Action("SharingReportDetailsByContactID", "Sharing", new {Id = item.ID})" data-toggle="ajaxModal" name="@item.ID" alt="@prefix @item.DisplayName" title="Edit Sharing"><i class="fa fa-edit  "></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="inline m-sm pointer deleteSharing" name="@item.ID" title="Delete Sharing"><i class="fa fa-times "></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="inline m-sm pointer" href="#" onclick=" SuspendSharing('@item.ID') " title="Suspend Sharing"><i class="fa fa-pause "></i>
                            </a>

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

In the above code if I use @item.ID in different td it matches the value but how to match hidden field value.I want to do something like

```
  var contactSelector = "td(input):contains('"+selectedContact+"')";
    $contactRow = $(contactSelector).closest("tr");//will give me row which I have updated
    $contactRow.find("td:nth-child(5)").text(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have the following html

```
<tr class='item'>
 <td class='itemId'>@item.ID</td>
 <input type="hidden" value="@item.ID" class='hiddenid'/>
 //other  html
</tr>
```

if you're trying to retrieve the id of the row by clicking on it use the following:

```
$('tr').on('click', function() {
    var id = $(this).find('.hiddenid').val();
    var parent = null;
    $('.itemId').each(function() {
     if ($(this).text() == id) {
      parent = $(this).parent(); // this is the matching <tr>
     }
    });
}
```

but I don't understand why you have a hidden input and a td with the id? you can just retrieve it from one of these two, no need to have it twice

I think you need to rewrite your question, you don't need to get the hidden input value, then use that to get the td

Comment: if my itemId is in different column its value is accessible but I want to get value fro here-  <td><input type="hidden" value="@item.ID"/>@item.Prefix @item.DisplayName
                        </td>

Comment: @rupinder18 give your input a class `<input class='itemId' type='hidden' value...etc/>`

Comment: its not working getting blank value I have tried adding item class to tr and td respectively and itemId class for hidden field still not working

Comment: sorry you have to use `.val()` instead of `.text()`

Comment: yes it's giving the value of ID now but its not returning that td so unable to get row and update my status value

Comment: Sorry man.. I don't understand what you're trying to do. Can you please make your question clearer so I can help better?

Comment: thanks for your effort I tried updtae2 but I am getting parent null

Comment: @rupinder18 you're probably using `'.hiddenTdClass'` you have to replace that with the class you have on your `<td>` that has the hidden id. I'll update my answer

Comment: now please see my table I have updated I have a td in which I have id in hidden field now I want to find column having this id and then by column will get row